# how can i get sharp edges?

Tags: modeling

I want to make a model that looks like the first picture (i just put a plane and i circle and extruded). The way i want to do it is like the second picture, this i made from a subdivided plane, where i used the loop tool on the corner face to create a circle and then extruded everything...but with the subdivide modifier, i can not get sharp edges where i want them..i tried as you can see in my picture to use the crease tool to select edges i want sharp, but i can not use it on all edges i want sharp, cause that deforms the cylinder shape..any advices?
[image]

[image]

Comment: re creating your mesh and using sharp edges in combination with crease edges works fine so maybe you are not creasing all the correct edges. try deselecting everything and use the **Sharp Edges** option in the Select tab. then use the creasing edges. you can manually adjust the angle of the sharpness if the results its not immediately what you want

Comment: Thank you! i will try and see if i understand what you mean..

Answer (score 1):

## Do not use the Subsurf modifier on everything you make

Subsurf modifier is not a must. It creates a lot of geometry that is not always necessary. Just model the geometry you need. You can have more vertices in the cylindrical part alone. You can use bevel modifiers to make the forms more realistic since objects rarely have completely sharp edges. Two bevels with the first forming loops to fix shading work nice:

[image]

You could also use [Y.A.V.N.E.](https://github.com/fedackb/yavne) add-on to calculate face area weighted normals to have nice shading with only one bevel.

You don't need those extra loops to hold this form:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for comment, well i know i dont need subsurf modifier for this model, but actually i just practice for a model of a game pad, to find out how to make the shape of a cylinder, attached to it (without using 2 different models). But i will have a look at your advices...

Comment: I see a lot of beginners over-using subsurf. It is not for everything. Most organic irregular forms will benefit from it, but manufactured things even if they have smooth or curved forms often can be modeled with bevels and other modelling tools without ever touching Subsurf this way having fewer polygons or more detail in places it is needed.

Comment: Ok, but this game pad model i try to do has allot of curved shapes so i guess a subsurf is a must to make it look good, the reason i want all edges on this example to be totaly sharp is just for learning, the game pad itself has some sharp edges where the cylinder shape touches the body of the game pad. it is not possible to post picture in comment or else i could post it.

Comment: Could you maybe post a link to a picture? Or the model of the game pad?

Comment: Yes..i started from a plane, and the subdividing is not the best, as i said just doing this for learning. would be happy for advice, maybe the best way is not to make this "cylinder thing" from the base mesh? but adding a cylinder instead, i think makes it harder? i mean i need to merge all vertex and so on.. https://imgur.com/a/Rgq3FQs

Comment: It is a challenging form. There is probably no right way to approach this. I would start with all the circles and place them where I know they are (just circles made of edges), then I would  try to define all other parts that I can understand the position of with only edges and vertices duplicating, moving, extruding, or using parts of a circle if they are curved. When I have a bunch of lines that I think are in the right positions in 3d space, I would try to fill the rest. But that is in no way the 'right' way, it's just a way. That is definitely a good object for a modelling exercise. :)

Comment: Oh, and yes, I think you are right, Subsurf is probably the best way to go with this.

Comment: Ok thanks for advice, i think i do it that way to so i can get the rest of faces better arranged.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add edge reinforcements before you apply the subsurface modifier.  Add edge loops and drag them toward the edge you want to reinforce(keep sharp).

[image]